# combining Geography data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Using something like this works:

```
DECLARE @Shape GEOGRAPHY  = 'POLYGON EMPTY'
SET @Shape.STSrid = 4326;

SELECT @Shape = @Shape.STUnion([PolygonData])
  FROM [Bla].[Polygon]

SELECT @Shape.STAsText();
```

on a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Space].[Polygon](
    [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL,
    [PolygonData] [GEOGRAPHY] NULL)
```

Unfortunately, it is very slow. I do not think I can index this so I wonder if there are alternative approaches that can be used to merge polygons to obtain just the outer points of the combined polygon. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried UnionAggregate?

Comment: @BenThul can I apply UnionAggregate to GEOGRAPHY?

Comment: I have had the luxury of controlling all data changes to the base polygons in stored procs.  I then create the STUnion Polygons and store them n other fieds and tables  when the core objects change... Similar to a data warehouse.     You test case may lead you down the wrong path.  Think of reporting (many polygons) or typical application usage of WHERE Clauses against the polygons.  That will get you thinking of where to put your indexes including GEOGRAPHIC INDEXES.  I often put a geo centerpoint as decimal lat long in their own fields query as par of this derived data.

Comment: Funny enough I have started similar approaches. Could you please post an answer?